# appoint class to PHP table with results from MYSQL db help

Tags: php, mysql, css

no border shows up when setting style in the table row below, inside the while loop? why? Background color setting works fine, but not this... NO BORDER SHOWS UP...

```
    // Build Result String
$display_table = "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){

$display_table .= "<tr style='border-top-width: thin; border-top-style: solid;'>"; //  wont work here, why?????

$display_table .= "<td width='110' rowspan='2'>BILD HÄR</td>";
$display_table .= "<td width='377' height='15'>$row[headline]</td>";
$display_table .= "<td width='67' rowspan='2'>$row[insert_date]</td>";
$display_table .= "</tr>";
$display_table .= "<tr>";
$display_table .= "<td height='15'>$row[price]:-</td>";
$display_table .= "</tr>";
}

$display_table .= "</table>";
echo $display_table;
```

Comment: What makes you think you can't do that? A PHP compiler error? Something wrong with the HTML output? A CSS parsing error? Something unexpected in the CSS rendering? Please be specific.

Comment: Ben - a game of "hunt the error" can sometimes be fun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the line

```
$display_table .= "<tr class="blablabla">";
```

Because if you look, you're closing the quotes just before blablabla, so PHP interprets that as PHP, not as a string.

If you need to use double quotes in a string, wrap the string in single quotes.

You'd so something like this in the above situation

```
$display_table .= '<tr class="blablabla">';
```

Have a look at [PHP's strings manual page](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: If you still want to use double-quotes, you can escape them like:
     $display_table .= "<tr class=\"blabala\">";
Or, as suggested use html single quotes.

A tip, it looks like you might be better just leavin the html as html, and adding php <?= or <?php echo $row[headline]; ?> into the html.

You could also consider using HEREDOCS for multi-line variables.

Comment: @CodeJoust: embedding php tags in html as you suggest it is bad coding style. It makes the code unreadable and unmaintainable.

Comment: camran changed the content of the question. Since he now asks a different question, the answer you provided is no longer relevant, hence the gone accepted answer :).

Answer (score 0):

```
$display_table .= "<tr class='blablabla'>";
```

or

```
$display_table .= "<tr class=\"blablabla\">";
```

obvious, since your closing your string with " in the middle of the line...

Comment: single quotes in HTML output? I'm pretty sure the standard is to use double!

Comment: it's still possible and he uses it anyway in the other tags.